# showInputDialog freezes other windows

Tags: java, swing, input, joptionpane

Im using several showInputDialogs in a program. 
When one of these input pops up it freezes all the other windows in the background until it has recieved an input, is there a way to make it not freeze the other windows?

Answer (score 3):

If by "freeze" you mean that the user cannot access the other windows, then the key is to make the new dialog a non-modal dialog. You can extract the JDialog from the JOptionPane and then elect to display it in a non-modal way. The [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) will show you how. Search for the section titled "Direct Use:"

Edit: as Andrew states as well! 1+

---

Playing with code....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JTextField textfield = new JTextField(10);
      textfield.setFocusable(false);
      final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(textfield);

      panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Push Me") {

         private JOptionPane optionPane;
         private JDialog dialog;
         private JTextField optionTextField = new JTextField(10);

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (dialog == null) {
               JPanel optionPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
               optionPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter some stuff"),
                     BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
               optionPanel.add(optionTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
               optionPane = new JOptionPane(optionPanel,
                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
               dialog = optionPane.createDialog(panel, "Get More Info");
               dialog.setModal(false);
               dialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                  @Override
                  public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                     Integer value = (Integer) optionPane.getValue();
                     if (value == null) {
                        return;
                     }
                     if (value == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        textfield.setText(optionTextField.getText());
                     }
                  }
               });
            }
            dialog.setVisible(true);
         }
      }));

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: *"Search for the section titled "Direct Use:""*  Ooh, I had not thought of that.  +1  It *is* a hassle to recreate the functionality of `JOptionPane`..

Comment: I checked it out but i don't see how it works with inputdialogs? i have inputdialogs in the styles of  tablename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter tablename *(use capital letters)");

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-modal `JDialog` instead.  See [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) for details.